# Decimate vector in eigen

Tags: c++, signal-processing, eigen

I have a float array Eigen::ArrayXf which I need to decimate (i.e. pick 1 out of f.i. 8 samples).

```
Eigen::ArrayXf decimatedSignal = Eigen::Map<Eigen::ArrayXf, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<8> >(signal.data(), length, 1).eval();
```

which works, with a caveat: I need to know how long length is, and it can be specified too long, leading to runtime errors.

Q: is there a way to decimate all that is possible, so that resultant length is == signal.size() / 8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. You are using the [c'tor](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html#a634c57f640ed589f49962cfbcc9389b2) for mapping a matrix:

> Map   (
>         PointerArgType      dataPtr,
>         Index   nbRows,
>         Index   nbCols,
>         const StrideType &      a_stride = StrideType() 
>     )
>
> Constructor in the dynamic-size matrix case.
>
> Parameters
>
> > ```
> > dataPtr  pointer to the array to map
> > nbRows    the number of rows of the matrix expression
> > nbCols    the number of columns of the matrix expression
> > a_stride  optional Stride object, passing the strides.
> > ```

I think you want the c'tor for a vector:

> Map   (   PointerArgType      dataPtr,
>         Index   a_size,
>         const StrideType &      a_stride = StrideType() 
>     )
>
> Constructor in the dynamic-size vector case.
>
> Parameters
>
> > ```
> > dataPtr  pointer to the array to map
> > a_size    the size of the vector expression
> > a_stride  optional Stride object, passing the strides.
> > ```

The second thing is that you want `length == signal.size())/8`. Is that always a whole integer, or are you rounding up? If the data is 16 in length and you want the positions `[0]` and `[8]`, then use `1+(signal.size()-1)/8` as the length parameter:

```
Eigen::ArrayXf decimatedSignal = Eigen::Map<Eigen::ArrayXf, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<8> >(signal.data(), 1+((signal.size()-1)/8) ).eval();
```

For example:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Eigen::VectorXf signal;
    signal.setLinSpaced(64, 0.0, 63.);
    cout << "Original signal:" << endl << signal.transpose() << endl;

    Eigen::ArrayXf decimatedSignal = Eigen::Map<Eigen::ArrayXf, 0, 
        Eigen::InnerStride<8> >(signal.data(), 1+((signal.size()-1)/8)).eval();

    cout << endl << "Decimated:" << endl << decimatedSignal.transpose() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

outputs

> Original signal:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
>
> Decimated:
>    0  8 16 24 32 40 48 56

which I think is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that is how I do it now. Opted for length = size/8.